# Query list of Objects from Installed Package

Tags: soql, custom-object, installedpackage

Is it possible to get the list of custom objects that are installed as part of an installed package with a SOQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tooling SOQL to get the custom objects installed as part of the package via the below query. Note its tooling query and not regular SOQL

```
Select ID, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName from CustomObject WHERE NamespacePrefix='<namespaceprefix of object>'
```

If you need this in apex use the Schema describe and get the objects using namespace Prefix

```
List<String> packageObjects = new List<String>();
  for (Schema.SObjectType obj: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
   String objectname = obj.getDescribe().getName();
   if(objectname.startsWith('<namespaceprefix>')) {
    packageObjects.add(objectname);
  }
}
System.debug(packageObjects);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.